# Cannot access my SQL Server  2008 by T4 template error is return to me how to get tables?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, t4

I want to generate some code using a T4 template. I am connecting using "sa" and sa's password. But I cannot connect to a remote SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Error is below :

> Error Running transformation:   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: SetParent
>   failed for Database 'FlyAnt'.  --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException:
>   Failed to connect to server MROAPPSQL. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user
>   'MROTECHNIC\yusuf.karatoprak'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.InternalConnect(WindowsIdentity
>   impersonatedIdentity)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.PoolConnect()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.get_ServerVersion()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetServerVersion()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.get_ServerVersion()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ValidateParent(SqlSmoObject
>   newParent)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.SetParentImpl(SqlSmoObject
>   newParent)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.SetParentImpl(SqlSmoObject
>   newParent)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database..ctor(Server server, String name)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating3B02A40A7B5CFF5BC85C47D46E8EE44A.GeneratedTextTransformation.CodeGenerator.RunCore()
>   at T4Toolbox.Generator.Run()
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating3B02A40A7B5CFF5BC85C47D46E8EE44A.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession
>   session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String&
>   result)

My code is this:

```
<#@ template language="C#"#>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml"#>


<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection"#>


   <#+
    public class CodeTemplate : Template
    {
        public string DatabaseName;
        public string ServerName;
        public string TableName;

        public override string TransformText()
        {
            Server server = new Server(ServerName);
                server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;

                server.ConnectionContext.Login = "sa";
                server.ConnectionContext.Password = "123456";
            server.ConnectionContext.Connect();
            Database database = new Database(server, DatabaseName);
            Table table = new Table(database, TableName);
            table.Refresh();

                string DataType= string.Empty;
            WriteLine("using System;\nusing System;\nusing System.Collections.Generic;\nusing System.Linq;\nusing System.Text;\n");

            WriteLine("namespace MyCustomEntities\n{");

            WriteLine("//Select");
                WriteLine("\tpublic partial class My" +table.Name+ "\n\t{");
            GenerateProperties(table);
                   //output the contructor
            WriteLine("\n\t\tpublic My" + table.Name + "()\n\t\t{\n\t\t//constructor\n\t\t}" );

            //end class
            WriteLine("\t}");
              WriteLine("//Update Delete Save");
                WriteLine("\tpublic partial class My" +table.Name+ "\n\t{");

                WriteLine("\t}");
                WriteLine("}");
            return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
          }

        protected void GenerateProperties( Table table)
        {
                 foreach (Column  column in table.Columns)
                {
                    switch(column.DataType.Name)
                    {
                        case "nvarchar":
                        case "varchar":
                        case "nchar":
                        case "char":
                            WriteLine("\t\tpublic string "+column.Name+"{ get; set;}");
                            break;
                        case "int":
                        case "smallint":
                        case "bigint":
                            WriteLine("\t\tpublic int "+column.Name+" { get; set;}");
                            break;
                        case "datetime":
                            WriteLine("\t\tpublic DateTime "+column.Name+" { get; set;}");
                            break;
                        case "image":
                            WriteLine("\t\tpublic byte[] "+column.Name+" { get; set;}");
                            break;
                        case "bit":
                            WriteLine("\t\tpublic bool "+column.Name+" { get; set;}");
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

   #>
```

My connection code :

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True"  #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml"#>
<#@ output extension="txt" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection"#>

<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #> 
<#@ include file="CodeGenerator.tt" #> 

<# 
    CodeGenerator gen = new CodeGenerator();

    gen.ServerName="MYSQLSERVER";
    gen.DatabaseName="FlyAnt";
    gen.Run();


#>
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you also don't need any annoying `&#62;` and so on ... just format your code properly!

Answer (score 1):

The exception message states that you're attempting to login using a Windows account, which is **the identity of the running process**:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user
>   'MROTECHNIC\yusuf.karatoprak'

If you look at the stack trace, you'll find that the failed connection attempt actually originates from [the constructor of the Database class that takes the Server object as argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms192729.aspx):

```
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
[...]
at Microsoft.SqServer.Management.Smo.Database..ctor(Server server, String name)
[...]
at T4Toolbox.Generator.Run()
```

It also seems that the generation process is being kicked off by [T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks everythink ok but : Compiling transformation: Identifier expected error occurs

Comment: server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false; is ok Server Autantication